# train caseless model for NER in openNLP

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I want to train model for extracting person name (part of NER system) but I want to make this model caseless (I mean the model will not take letter case in consideration, no difference between uppercase and lowercase letters), because i have noisy text.

so is there any parameter in training step to do that, or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use OpenNLP, I suppose you could train new models on caseless training data. Simply take whatever existing training data is available (with appropriate annotations, etc.) and lowercase all the content before training a new model.

Or, if you can use Stanford NER instead of OpenNLP, you can just use Stanford NER's pre-trained caseless English models: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml#Models

Whichever way you go, keep in mind that your accuracy will decrease by using caseless models.

Comment: what stanford NER uses for caseless model? , the caseless model that i trained by openNLP not comparable with stanford caseless model. stanford NER gives very good result for people names extraction.

Comment: The caseless models for Stanford NER are simply caseless (i.e., lowercased) versions of the 3 regular English Stanford NER models: a 4 class model trained for CoNLL, a 7 class model trained for MUC, and a 3 class model trained on the intersection of both data sets. You can download the caseless models here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-caseless-2014-02-25-models.jar

Comment: I already tried it, but i wonder why stanford NER gives much better result than openNLP NER, i mean what is the main difference between them? thanks a lot @Charlie for your help.

Comment: The Stanford NLP Group programmers, algorithms, and training data are superior to OpenNLP's programmers, algorithms, and training data. :)